# Entity Framework Bug, extra decimal places

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I think I have found a bug in EF5, but I want to verify that this isn't some weird behavior there is a known fix for (nothing on Google or Bing as far as I can see).

I'm doing a select on a database value that is 0.06 in a field that is decimal(18,2).  I ran the query I expected EF to generate and got .06 back, I took the sql profiler query that ef ran an also got .06 back.  In my code however, I got .0675.  I checked the EDMX field and it has a matching precision/scale of 18,2.

My data is "1 version with 4 sets" so my query does a where clause on the version number and then gets 4 rows back, but only row 3 gets the weird value.  Row 1, 2, and 4 are .03, .04, and .12 and they return as such, but row 3 is .06 but returns as .0675.

Last thing that could be useful is the EF proxies are the only part that is wrong.  If I select the EF Proxies, that is when this pops up, but if I do the select into my viewmodel the correct value is returned.

```
_entities.Sets.Where(x => x.VersionID == versionID) // ---> returns bad value
_entities.Sets.Where(x => x.VersionID == versionID).Select(x => new VM { Rate = x.Rate}) // ---> returns correctly
```

Any ideas on this behavior?

EDIT:
Appears I do not even need a model to select into, even selecting just the field I want back returns correctly so I think I'm going to submit a bug to Microsoft:

```
_entities.Sets.Where(x => x.VersionID == versionID).Select(x => x.Rate)  // ---> returns .06 correctly
```

Comment: If you had made this an answer, I would give it to you.  Found a rogue spot in my code that was loading .0675 when I wasn't expecting it so it was cached in the proxy even though it made the db query.  Yay static contexts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess the proxy object was previously loaded with the value being .0675. so unless you explicitly reload, it does not change the value when it's queried via proxy as the value would be the same given the precision of 2. If that's the case then it's not a bug as much as of a matter of perspective. To the database it's .06, to the app it's still .0675, both are legitimate.